# Arithmetic overflow with fontspec and LuaTeX

Tags: errors, fontspec, luatex

I have the following code using [this font](https://github.com/georgd/EB-Granjon/blob/master/OTF/EBGaramondInitialsF2.otf):

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{fontspec,xunicode}

\newfontfamily\EBLettrineFont{EBGaramondInitialsF2}
\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\EBLettrineFont}

\begin{document}

\lettrine{T}{his} is a test


\end{document}
```

It works fine with  `xelatex`, but crashes with `lualatex`:

```
! Arithmetic overflow.
\LettrineFont ...\divide \@tempcnta by \@tempcntb 
                                                  \advance \@tempcnta by -99...
l.11 \lettrine{T}{his}
                       is a test
?
```

What is wrong?

Comment: is this font free available for download?

Comment: When I try to compile your example with `lualatex` (beta-0.65.0-2011041019 (rev 4033) from Ubuntu's TL2009) I get another error, I get `XeTeX is required to compile this document.`.

Comment: @Herbert: the link is in the question (where it says "this font").

Comment: @N.N. Up-to-date TL2011 has LuaTeX beta-0.70.1-2011061410 (rev 4277)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `lettrine` package depends on the font having the character `X` in order to perform its calculations; and this font, it seems, does not have the character. The `lettrine` macro in question is `\LettrineFont`. It constructs a box containing the `X` in a given font and then measures its height. For this font and this character, LuaTeX reports a box height of 0 pt. A following integer division then fails.

Strictly speaking, the `lettrine` assumption is fair and the font is at fault for not providing even a minimal set of characters. If you still want to use this font, the easiest way is to modify `\LettrineFont` to use a character that exists in this font, such as `O`:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{fontspec,xunicode}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newfontfamily\EBLettrineFont{EBGaramondInitialsF2}
\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\EBLettrineFont}

\patchcmd{\LettrineFont}{\selectfont X}{\selectfont O}{}{%
  \GenericWarning{}{Patching \protect\LettrineFont\space failed}}

\begin{document}

\lettrine{T}{his} is a test

\end{document}
```

XeTeX, unlike LuaTeX, returns the height of nonexistent `X` as 8.10722 pt with this example code, and therefore division by zero does not occur.